# getSignedRequest Facebook SDK 4

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm creating a Fan gate on Facebook SDK 4,

I'm trying to use **$signed_request = $facebook->getSignedRequest();**

However, I'm currently not sure which object I should be calling getSignedRequest() on.

The doc says $facebook, when I create a $facebook object from
`$facebook = FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication('app_id 'secret');`

I get the following error

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function getSignedRequest() on a non-object
```

CODE

```
$facebook = FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication('app_id', 'secret);

// login helper with redirect_uri
$helper = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper( 'http://www.metah.ch/' );

try {
  $session = $helper->getSessionFromRedirect();
} catch( FacebookRequestException $ex ) {
  // When Facebook returns an error
} catch( Exception $ex ) {
  // When validation fails or other local issues
}

$signed_request = $facebook->getSignedRequest();

var_dump($signed_request);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't imagine that `FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication('app_id', 'secret');` returns a facebook object. You can try to `var_dump($facebook);` to confirm.

The docs didn't seem to suggest it returned a facebook object either. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/gettingstarted/4.0.0

I haven't used the SDK in some time but it used to be that you'd do `new Facebook()` to get a facebook object. The docs seem to indicate the `getSignedRequest` method exists in the `BaseFacebook` class. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/facebook-getSignedRequest

Comment: Hey Jaisen,
Your right about the FacebookSession not returning an object, the vardump shows NULL.

I also do recall the old SDK allow for new Facebook() to create an object.

It seems that "getSignedRequest" is apart of BaseFacebook, with that said, not quite sure what to call the method on.

Comment: Looks like `FacebookSession` has that method defined. https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk-v4/blob/56d40c32400bcf36d41d4224bfee1406c5dba962/src/Facebook/FacebookSession.php#L105